# Subdividing a string and using substrings as fraction components

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to return a set of string values from a mySQL query. Then separate them at the '/' character (which they all contain). And finally divide the value before the '/' character, by the value that follows it.

I've tried casting the SUBSTRING as an INT and several DECIMAL variations. Any help gratefully accepted.

```
        "
        CAST(
            CAST(
                SUBSTRING(
                    customerfeedback.total_score, 
                    0, LOCATE('/', table.column_a-1)
                )AS DECIMAL(6,3)
            )
            /
            CAST(
                SUBSTRING(
                    customerfeedback.total_score,
                    LOCATE('/', table.column_a+1), LENGTH(table.column_a)
                )AS DECIMAL(6,3)
            )
            AS DECIMAL(6,3)
        )
        "
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring_index` to extract the numerator and denominator parts and use them in division.

**Example**:

```
select 
  @str:='225/12', 
  @n:=substring_index( @str, '/', 1 ) numerator, 
  @d:=substring_index( @str, '/', -1 ) denominator, 
  @n/@d quotient;
```

**Result of the above example**:

```
+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| @str:='225/12' | numerator | denominator | quotient |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
| 225/12         | 225       | 12          |    18.75 |
+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

You can cast or round of the quotient as desired.